# How to access linked bean fields with RedBean and Twig?

Tags: php, twig, redbean

I have a bean (foo) being linked to another bean (bar) and want to access the other bean's (bar's) fields within Twig. First, an example of how I'm setting up the beans

```
$f = R::dispense('foo');
$f->name = 'foo';

$b = R::dipsense('bar');
$b->val = 10;
R::store($b);

$f->bar = $b;
R::store($f);
```

I know there are no issues here because everything database is updated correctly. Now, using twig:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for f in siteinfo.foos %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{f.name}}</td>
                <td>{{f.bar.val}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm certain almost everything works because I get a table with names printed correctly however no 'bar' values are printed. `siteinfo.foos` returns `R::findAll('foo', 'order by name');`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Redbean works with lazy load, first of all, you need to know if this var in twig is a bean or a stdClass or array, you can check this printing the bean {{bean|var_dump}}

Comment: It crashes because `var_dump` is an unknown filter.

Comment: It appears to be loading as an array. Printing `<p>f</p>` in the for loop gives: {"id":"14","name":"foo","bar_id":"1"}

Comment: is there a way to `R::load('bar', $bar_id)` from within twig?

Comment: If you extend Twig you could otherwise `R` will be unkown to Twig

Comment: if it's a json when printing, then you have a bean object, redbean implementos __toString magic method and it return a json_encoded string

Comment: try to load the related information before passing the bean to the view, just to test if it works

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
    {% for f in siteinfo.foos %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{f.name}}</td>
            <td>{{f.__get('bar').val}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

The use of `__get()` forces the evaluation of the property by the RedBean library.